# The logarithm of an operator

Tags: operator-theory, functional-calculus

I am currently learning statistical physics and the logarithm of operators plays an important role, since the entropy is $S=k_B\ln\langle\rho\rangle$, where $\rho$ is a density operator.

Unfortunately, phisicists don't mention how $\ln\rho$ is defined and i couldn't find more information on the internet.

Since the exponential of an operator $A$ can be written as

$$e^A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n!}$$
and for $1-1<x\leq 1+1$ we have the formula
$$\ln x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{n},$$
I was wondering whether I can calculate the logarithm of an operator by exchaning $x-1$ with $A-\mathrm{id}$, where id is the identity.

Comment: If your operator is bounded and the norm of $A-\mathrm{Id}$ is smaller than $1$, then yes, the series works. For self-adjoint operators, one uses the spectral Theorem to define more generally $f(\rho)$ by first diagonalizing $\rho$ and then applying the function to each element of the spectrum.